# Create customized Jasper report layout

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I would like to create a report that has the following layout:
[image]

It has three parts as you can see. The third part is a subreport done as a list, that is the easy part! My question is this: is there a better way of doing the first two parts than drawing boxes and lines in element groups and doing crazy calculations with positioning them? (I am talking about the .jrxml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport). It is a gui application for designing jasper reports.

You can drag and drop text fields and other report elements, so you don't have to worry about positioning.

Comment: I have tried iReport but then my Jasper (version 3.7.5) does not recognize the jrxml file.

Comment: @Atticus The new version of iReport should with 3.7.5. Can you post your errors or possibly start your report again just using iReport?

Comment: I have found the solution and posted it as an answer! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have had several problems using the `.jrxml` gerenated by iReport, but finally I have found an [artikle](http://knol.google.com/k/jasper-reports-working-with-beans-and-sub-report#) that explains how to use iReport. It also explains how to fill the report. 
I have had problems since I was using a manually written `.jrxml`, which had to be compiled and filled. Now based on the code in the artikel I am not using `.jrxml` anymore, but the `.jasper` file compiled by the iReport and everything works like a charm.